# Is there a case where an html element can't be removed?

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute, removechild

I have this html code (snipped below) and I am trying to completely remove the element with data-doctype="Comment" and all its children.

With this code I can get my element (which is certain as the .innerHTML returned by the console log display the right html), but the child is not removed, neither with obj.removeChild(child);, nor with child.remove();. A  .hide() doesn't work either btw.

Do you have any idea of the reason why I can't remove it and how to remove it properly ?

To give you a better understanding of the situation, here is the current css displayed.

[I want to get rid of the whole comment section seen here. When I manually delete the element in the html, it disappears correctly, but the .remove() don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM92I.png)

```js
var objects = document.getElementsByClassName('timeline-items');
for (var obj of objects) {
  for (var child of obj.children) {
    if (child.getAttribute('data-doctype') == "Comment") {
      //console.log(child.innerHTML)
      obj.removeChild(child);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="new-timeline">
  <div class="timeline-item activity-toggle">
    <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content flex align-center">
      <h4>Activity</h4>
      <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-row">
        <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" data-only-communication="true">Communication</a>
        <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active">All</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-items timeline-actions" style="">
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content action-buttons"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary-dark action-btn">
            <svg class="icon  icon-xs" style="">
            <use class="" href="#icon-mail"></use>
        </svg>
            New Email
        </button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <span>Add to this activity by mailing to <b><a class="document-email-link">ioi.system.auto+ioi%20Ticket+COMPT%20%E2%80%A2%2000000001@gmail.com</a></b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-items">
    <div class="timeline-item" data-doctype="Comment" data-name="54c14ee6c1">
      <div class="timeline-badge" title="SmallMessage">
        <svg class="icon  icon-md" style="">
            <use class="" href="#icon-small-message"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-content frappe-card" id="comment-54c14ee6c1">
        <div class="timeline-message-box" data-communication-type=""> <span class="flex justify-between">   <span class="text-color flex">         <span>      You commented      <span class="text-muted margin-left">       <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-08 14:49:37.423311" title="08-09-2022 14:49:37">2 hours ago</span>          </span>
          </span>
          </span> <span class="actions">             <div class="custom-actions"><button class="btn btn-link action-btn">Edit</button><button class="btn btn-link action-btn" style="display: none;">
                Dismiss
            </button></div>    <div class="more-actions">     <a type="button" class="action-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">      <svg class="icon icon-sm">       <use href="#icon-dot-horizontal"></use>      </svg>     </a>     <ul class="dropdown-menu small">      <li>       <a class="dropdown-item" data-action="copy_link">Copy Link</a>      </li>     <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </li></ul>    </div>   </span> </span>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="ql-editor read-mode">
              <p>zffzf</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-edit-box" style="display: none;">
            <div class="frappe-control" data-fieldtype="Comment" data-fieldname="comment">
              <div class="ql-container ql-bubble" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true">
                  <p>zffzf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ql-tooltip ql-hidden"><span class="ql-tooltip-arrow"></span>
                  <div class="ql-tooltip-editor"><input type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL">
                    <a class="ql-close"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ql-toolbar"><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-bold"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,4H9.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,12,6.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.5,9H5A0,0,0,0,1,5,9V4A0,0,0,0,1,5,4Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,9h5.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,13,11.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,10.5,14H5a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V9A0,0,0,0,1,5,9Z"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-italic"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="13" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="11" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="8" x2="10" y1="14" y2="4"></line> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-underline"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,3V9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4,4H9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4-4V3"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="12" x="3" y="15"></rect> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-strike"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke ql-thin" x1="15.5" x2="2.5" y1="8.5" y2="9.5"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M9.007,8C6.542,7.791,6,7.519,6,6.5,6,5.792,7.283,5,9,5c1.571,0,2.765.679,2.969,1.309a1,1,0,0,0,1.9-.617C13.356,4.106,11.354,3,9,3,6.2,3,4,4.538,4,6.5a3.2,3.2,0,0,0,.5,1.843Z"></path> <path class="ql-fill" d="M8.984,10C11.457,10.208,12,10.479,12,11.5c0,0.708-1.283,1.5-3,1.5-1.571,0-2.765-.679-2.969-1.309a1,1,0,1,0-1.9.617C4.644,13.894,6.646,15,9,15c2.8,0,5-1.538,5-3.5a3.2,3.2,0,0,0-.5-1.843Z"></path> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-blockquote"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <rect class="ql-fill ql-stroke" height="3" width="3" x="4" y="5"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill ql-stroke" height="3" width="3" x="11" y="5"></rect> <path class="ql-even ql-fill ql-stroke" d="M7,8c0,4.031-3,5-3,5"></path> <path class="ql-even ql-fill ql-stroke" d="M14,8c0,4.031-3,5-3,5"></path> </svg></button>
                      <button
                        type="button" class="ql-code-block"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polyline class="ql-even ql-stroke" points="5 7 3 9 5 11"></polyline> <polyline class="ql-even ql-stroke" points="13 7 15 9 13 11"></polyline> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="10" x2="8" y1="5" y2="13"></line> </svg></button>
                        </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-direction" value="rtl"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-stroke ql-fill" points="3 11 5 9 3 7 3 11"></polygon> <line class="ql-stroke ql-fill" x1="15" x2="11" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M11,3a3,3,0,0,0,0,6h1V3H11Z"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="11" y="4"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="13" y="4"></rect> </svg><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-stroke ql-fill" points="15 12 13 10 15 8 15 12"></polygon> <line class="ql-stroke ql-fill" x1="9" x2="5" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M5,3A3,3,0,0,0,5,9H6V3H5Z"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="5" y="4"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="7" y="4"></rect> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-link"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="11" y1="7" y2="11"></line> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M8.9,4.577a3.476,3.476,0,0,1,.36,4.679A3.476,3.476,0,0,1,4.577,8.9C3.185,7.5,2.035,6.4,4.217,4.217S7.5,3.185,8.9,4.577Z"></path> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M13.423,9.1a3.476,3.476,0,0,0-4.679-.36,3.476,3.476,0,0,0,.36,4.679c1.392,1.392,2.5,2.542,4.679.36S14.815,10.5,13.423,9.1Z"></path> </svg></button>
                          <button
                            type="button" class="ql-image"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <rect class="ql-stroke" height="10" width="12" x="3" y="4"></rect> <circle class="ql-fill" cx="6" cy="7" r="1"></circle> <polyline class="ql-even ql-fill" points="5 12 5 11 7 9 8 10 11 7 13 9 13 12 5 12"></polyline> </svg></button>
                            </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="ordered"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke ql-thin" x1="2.5" x2="4.5" y1="5.5" y2="5.5"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M3.5,6A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3,5.5V3.085l-0.276.138A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,2.053,3c-0.124-.247-0.023-0.324.224-0.447l1-.5A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,4,2.5v3A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3.5,6Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M4.5,10.5h-2c0-.234,1.85-1.076,1.85-2.234A0.959,0.959,0,0,0,2.5,8.156"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M2.5,14.846a0.959,0.959,0,0,0,1.85-.109A0.7,0.7,0,0,0,3.75,14a0.688,0.688,0,0,0,.6-0.736,0.959,0.959,0,0,0-1.85-.109"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="bullet"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><span class="ql-align ql-picker ql-icon-picker"><span class="ql-picker-label" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ql-picker-options-8"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="13" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span class="ql-picker-options" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="ql-picker-options-8"><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="13" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="center"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="14" x2="4" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="12" x2="6" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="right"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="5" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="justify"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                    <select class="ql-align" style="display: none;">
                      <option selected="selected"></option>
                      <option value="center"></option>
                      <option value="right"></option>
                      <option value="justify"></option>
                    </select>
                    </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-clean"><svg class="" viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="13" y1="3" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="9.35" y1="12" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="11" x2="15" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="11" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="7" x="2" y="14"></rect> </svg></button></span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ql-mention-list-container" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
                  <ul class="ql-mention-list"></ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content ">You created this <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-05 16:40:10.830599" title="05-09-2022 16:40:10">3 days ago</span> • You edited this <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-08 14:44:20.786271" title="08-09-2022 14:44:20">2 hours ago</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make a runnable snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and "edit above snippet" and provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: where is the "dismiss" and "zffzf" in your output? Seems the code does the job?

Comment: You can just disable comments from doctype

Comment: Hello Shridar, I want some specific users (defined by role) to be able to access comments and prevent any other user to see the comments in this doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code does work, but it can certainly be simplified to not iterate a live collection returned by `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-item[data-doctype=Comment]')
  .forEach(comment => comment.remove())
```

```html
<div class="new-timeline">
  <div class="timeline-item activity-toggle">
    <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content flex align-center">
      <h4>Activity</h4>
      <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-row">
        <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" data-only-communication="true">Communication</a>
        <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active">All</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-items timeline-actions" style="">
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content action-buttons"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary-dark action-btn">
            <svg class="icon  icon-xs" style="">
            <use class="" href="#icon-mail"></use>
        </svg>
            New Email
        </button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <span>Add to this activity by mailing to <b><a class="document-email-link">ioi.system.auto+ioi%20Ticket+COMPT%20%E2%80%A2%2000000001@gmail.com</a></b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-items">
    <div class="timeline-item" data-doctype="Comment" data-name="54c14ee6c1">
      <div class="timeline-badge" title="SmallMessage">COMMENT
        <svg class="icon  icon-md" style="">
            <use class="" href="#icon-small-message"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-content frappe-card" id="comment-54c14ee6c1">
        <div class="timeline-message-box" data-communication-type=""> <span class="flex justify-between">   <span class="text-color flex">         <span>      You commented      <span class="text-muted margin-left">       <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-08 14:49:37.423311" title="08-09-2022 14:49:37">2 hours ago</span>          </span>
          </span>
          </span> <span class="actions">             <div class="custom-actions"><button class="btn btn-link action-btn">Edit</button><button class="btn btn-link action-btn" style="display: none;">
                Dismiss
            </button></div>    <div class="more-actions">     <a type="button" class="action-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">      <svg class="icon icon-sm">       <use href="#icon-dot-horizontal"></use>      </svg>     </a>     <ul class="dropdown-menu small">      <li>       <a class="dropdown-item" data-action="copy_link">Copy Link</a>      </li>     <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </li></ul>    </div>   </span> </span>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="ql-editor read-mode">
              <p>zffzf</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-edit-box" style="display: none;">
            <div class="frappe-control" data-fieldtype="Comment" data-fieldname="comment">
              <div class="ql-container ql-bubble" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true">
                  <p>zffzf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ql-tooltip ql-hidden"><span class="ql-tooltip-arrow"></span>
                  <div class="ql-tooltip-editor"><input type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL">
                    <a class="ql-close"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ql-toolbar"><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-bold"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,4H9.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,12,6.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.5,9H5A0,0,0,0,1,5,9V4A0,0,0,0,1,5,4Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,9h5.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,13,11.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,10.5,14H5a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V9A0,0,0,0,1,5,9Z"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-italic"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="13" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="11" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="8" x2="10" y1="14" y2="4"></line> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-underline"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,3V9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4,4H9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4-4V3"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="12" x="3" y="15"></rect> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-strike"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke ql-thin" x1="15.5" x2="2.5" y1="8.5" y2="9.5"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M9.007,8C6.542,7.791,6,7.519,6,6.5,6,5.792,7.283,5,9,5c1.571,0,2.765.679,2.969,1.309a1,1,0,0,0,1.9-.617C13.356,4.106,11.354,3,9,3,6.2,3,4,4.538,4,6.5a3.2,3.2,0,0,0,.5,1.843Z"></path> <path class="ql-fill" d="M8.984,10C11.457,10.208,12,10.479,12,11.5c0,0.708-1.283,1.5-3,1.5-1.571,0-2.765-.679-2.969-1.309a1,1,0,1,0-1.9.617C4.644,13.894,6.646,15,9,15c2.8,0,5-1.538,5-3.5a3.2,3.2,0,0,0-.5-1.843Z"></path> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-blockquote"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <rect class="ql-fill ql-stroke" height="3" width="3" x="4" y="5"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill ql-stroke" height="3" width="3" x="11" y="5"></rect> <path class="ql-even ql-fill ql-stroke" d="M7,8c0,4.031-3,5-3,5"></path> <path class="ql-even ql-fill ql-stroke" d="M14,8c0,4.031-3,5-3,5"></path> </svg></button>
                      <button
                        type="button" class="ql-code-block"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polyline class="ql-even ql-stroke" points="5 7 3 9 5 11"></polyline> <polyline class="ql-even ql-stroke" points="13 7 15 9 13 11"></polyline> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="10" x2="8" y1="5" y2="13"></line> </svg></button>
                        </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-direction" value="rtl"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-stroke ql-fill" points="3 11 5 9 3 7 3 11"></polygon> <line class="ql-stroke ql-fill" x1="15" x2="11" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M11,3a3,3,0,0,0,0,6h1V3H11Z"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="11" y="4"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="13" y="4"></rect> </svg><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-stroke ql-fill" points="15 12 13 10 15 8 15 12"></polygon> <line class="ql-stroke ql-fill" x1="9" x2="5" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M5,3A3,3,0,0,0,5,9H6V3H5Z"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="5" y="4"></rect> <rect class="ql-fill" height="11" width="1" x="7" y="4"></rect> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-link"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="11" y1="7" y2="11"></line> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M8.9,4.577a3.476,3.476,0,0,1,.36,4.679A3.476,3.476,0,0,1,4.577,8.9C3.185,7.5,2.035,6.4,4.217,4.217S7.5,3.185,8.9,4.577Z"></path> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M13.423,9.1a3.476,3.476,0,0,0-4.679-.36,3.476,3.476,0,0,0,.36,4.679c1.392,1.392,2.5,2.542,4.679.36S14.815,10.5,13.423,9.1Z"></path> </svg></button>
                          <button
                            type="button" class="ql-image"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <rect class="ql-stroke" height="10" width="12" x="3" y="4"></rect> <circle class="ql-fill" cx="6" cy="7" r="1"></circle> <polyline class="ql-even ql-fill" points="5 12 5 11 7 9 8 10 11 7 13 9 13 12 5 12"></polyline> </svg></button>
                            </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="ordered"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke ql-thin" x1="2.5" x2="4.5" y1="5.5" y2="5.5"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M3.5,6A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3,5.5V3.085l-0.276.138A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,2.053,3c-0.124-.247-0.023-0.324.224-0.447l1-.5A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,4,2.5v3A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3.5,6Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M4.5,10.5h-2c0-.234,1.85-1.076,1.85-2.234A0.959,0.959,0,0,0,2.5,8.156"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M2.5,14.846a0.959,0.959,0,0,0,1.85-.109A0.7,0.7,0,0,0,3.75,14a0.688,0.688,0,0,0,.6-0.736,0.959,0.959,0,0,0-1.85-.109"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="bullet"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line> </svg></button></span>
                    <span class="ql-formats"><span class="ql-align ql-picker ql-icon-picker"><span class="ql-picker-label" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ql-picker-options-8"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="13" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span class="ql-picker-options" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="ql-picker-options-8"><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="13" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="center"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="14" x2="4" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="12" x2="6" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="right"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="5" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    <span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="justify"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line> </svg></span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                    <select class="ql-align" style="display: none;">
                      <option selected="selected"></option>
                      <option value="center"></option>
                      <option value="right"></option>
                      <option value="justify"></option>
                    </select>
                    </span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-clean"><svg class="" viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="13" y1="3" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="9.35" y1="12" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="11" x2="15" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="11" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="7" x="2" y="14"></rect> </svg></button></span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ql-mention-list-container" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
                  <ul class="ql-mention-list"></ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="timeline-dot"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content ">You created this <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-05 16:40:10.830599" title="05-09-2022 16:40:10">3 days ago</span> • You edited this <span class="frappe-timestamp " data-timestamp="2022-09-08 14:44:20.786271" title="08-09-2022 14:44:20">2 hours ago</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, 

I agree your proposal is way better as it focus directly on the right element.

I didn't know this syntax of querySelectorAll btw so thank you.


However the principal issue persists, the element is not removed.

Comment: But it is removed in the code above. What is still there according to you? I remove the `<div class="timeline-item" data-doctype="Comment" > ...........</div>` and that includes all child elements. Please show me what is NOT removed - I think you mean something else

Comment: It was my fault, I was calling the function "before-load" and not also on "refresh" and didn't realize before-load only reacted the first time I loaded the webpage.

I guess my code worked too but didn't trigger for the same reason but your proposal is way better so I am glad I asked. I have learned many things.

Comment: Thank you very much once again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. PS: is is not the const. It is the querySelectorAll that accesses a static nodeList whereas [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) gets a live HTMLCollection

Comment: Oh, thank you for the tip.
I already intended to use the querySelectorAll in the future. It is way better to be able to use a real CSS selector. I have one more reason now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **live collections** and removing from them while iterating - that's almost always a recipe for disaster.

Here's a shorter version that avoids the footgun:

```js
for (const {children} of document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-items')) {
  [...children].forEach(child => child.dataset.doctype === 'Comment' && child.remove())
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.
I will use mplungjan structure as it seems easier to understand and able to focus quicklier on the targeted elements, but I will remember the use of const to avoid being in a live collection.

Comment: Thanks for both your help I know now how to properly use static collections with the querySelectorAll. Thank you.